# Unable to execute command with forward slash

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file to execute a set of Git commands to:

1. Fetch a new remote repository.
2. Create a local repository to track the remote and check the new local branch out.

Second Git command uses a forward slash (`origin/[repositoryName]`) and gives the following error:

> "fatal: Missing branch name; try `-b`".

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /P branch = Enter remote branch name:
git fetch origin %branch%
git checkout --track origin/%branch%
```

First, `git` command fetches the remote repository.

Second `git` command gives error:

> "fatal: "Missing branch name; try `-b`"

Comment: My guess is that --track only makes sense if you are checking out a local branch? Because of the way you are doing the checkout, it will only set you on `detached HEAD` and won't create a local branch. try `git checkout --track -b %branch% origin/%branch%`

Comment: Remove the space around the `=` symbol

Comment: @eftshift0: there are two ways to create a local branch (call it alpha) which tracks remote branch (also alpha): 1) git checkout -b alpha origin/alpha or 2) git checkout --track alpha origin/alpha.  The second version is a bit of a shortcut - it creates a local branch with the same name as the remote and makes the local track the remote.  The first version gives you the option to name a local branch differently from the remote branch that it is expected to track (at least per my understanding).  My issue is how do I deal with the forward slash in a bat file.

Comment: As mentioned, your problem should go if you replace `SET /P branch = Enter remote branch name:` with `SET /P branch=Enter remote branch name:` and enter a valid branch name. Note that `set /p branch = ...` is creating a variable with name `%branch %`, so either (not recommended) replace `%branch%` with `%branch %` or the solution I mentioned above.

Comment: @double-peep: Thanks.  Worked like a charm

Comment: @user6860460 consider reading the help file for the a command before asking a question. You can do so by opening a command prompt and typing: `set /?` The syntax for the `SET` command clearly shows no space between the variable name and the equals symbol: `SET [variable=[string]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you should use the following piece of code:

```bat
@echo off
set /p "branch=Enter remote branch name: "
git fetch origin %branch%
git checkout --track origin/%branch%
```

which is slightly modified.

- You don't need to scream in batch file :) it is a case insensitive language.
- When you set variables don't add extra spaces around the `=`. Because then, interpreter interprets it as `var<space>` and `<space>value`.
- Also, quote variable name and value in format like: `set "var=value"`.